# VUEJS vue-router access router from nested routes

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router

I have problem to access route object from nested views. Here is the simplified code:

main.js

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.use(Vuetify)

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes : [
    {path : '/contacts', component: Contacts,
      children: [
        {
          path: ':id',
          component: ContactDetails
        }
      ]
    },
  ],
  mode: 'history'
})


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App),
  router
})
```

ContactDetails.vue

```
<template>
    <v-btn icon dark class="mr-3" @click.native="editContact">
            <v-icon>edit</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        data : () => ({

        }),
        methods: {
           editContact: ()=>{
                console.log('edit contact');
                this.$router.go(-1) //this gives an error
           } 
        },


    }
</script>
```

It says "router is undefined", when I use

```
this.$router.go(-1)
```

from main routes (aka /contacts), it works. I tried all of the below code on the child:

```
router.go(-1)
$router.go(-1)
this.$router.go(-1)
this.router.go(-1)
this.$parent.$router.go(-1)
```

None of them works. Is there a way to  reach to router object from nested routes? Or should I emit an event to parent and change view from there?

Comment: You don't need to emit events, your child components have default access to your router instance. Can you show us `Contacts` component code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an error in your code - it's in `()=>{...}` function :)

Using an arrow function you are addressing `ContactDetails`-component `this` (object) and it does not contain any `$router` indeed. After you change an arrow function to `function() {}` your code will work as expected, because Vue rebinded to its instance where the `$router` is declared.

Now, lets look at this [working copy (codepen)](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xMKxmM) of your code:

```js
Vue.use(VueRouter)

let ContactDetails = {
    mounted() {
      console.log('ContactDetails mounted...');
    },
    methods: {
       editContact: function() {
            console.log('edit contact');
            this.$router.go(-1) //this DOES NOT give an error ANYMORE
       } 
    },
    template: `<button @click="editContact">edit</button>`,
}
let Contacts = {
  components: {ContactDetails},
  mounted() {
    console.log('Contacts mounted...');
  },
  template: `Contacts... <ContactDetails></ContactDetails>`,
};

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'hash',
  routes : [{
      path : '/contacts',
      component: Contacts,
      children: [{
          path: 'id',
          component: ContactDetails
        }]
    }],
});

const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    Contacts,
    ContactDetails,
  },
  router
});

vm.$router.push("/contacts/id");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-router/3.0.2/vue-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```